# Javascript-Jquery - How to call function only once upon either click on scroll event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Following is the script that I am trying to run when the class "skills" is clicked. It only works one time when clicked after that it won't run no matter how many times it's clicked

You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/tvEC5/

I want to modify it, add scroll functionality and make it only execute once when either clicked or scrolled, it should not execute after that.

Thank you.

```
var skillsClicked = false;   // <----  Add this OUTSIDE of the click function
$('.skills').on('click', function () {
    if (skillsClicked === true) return false;  // <---- Then add this
    skillsClicked = true;     // <-----  And the final update
    var gaugeConfig = {
        "canvasHolderId": "HTML",
            "width": "150",
            "height": "150",
            "circleColor": "#222",
            "arcColor": "#2ECC71",
            "canvasFillColor": "#333",
            "textPosition": "inside",
            "skillLevel": "7.5"
    };
    var gaugeConfig1 = {
        "canvasHolderId": "CSS",
            "width": "150",
            "height": "150",
            "circleColor": "#222",
            "arcColor": "#2ECC71",
            "canvasFillColor": "#333",
            "textPosition": "inside",
            "skillLevel": "6.5"
    };
    var gaugeConfig2 = {
        "canvasHolderId": "JS",
            "width": "150",
            "height": "150",
            "circleColor": "#222",
            "arcColor": "#27AE60",
            "canvasFillColor": "#333",
            "textPosition": "inside",
            "skillLevel": "7"
    };
    var gaugeConfig3 = {
        "canvasHolderId": "JQ",
            "width": "150",
            "height": "150",
            "circleColor": "#222",
            "arcColor": "#F1C40F",
            "canvasFillColor": "#333",
            "textPosition": "inside",
            "skillLevel": "7"
    };
    var gaugeConfig4 = {
        "canvasHolderId": "BT",
            "width": "150",
            "height": "150",
            "circleColor": "#222",
            "arcColor": "#F1C40F",
            "canvasFillColor": "#333",
            "textPosition": "inside",
            "skillLevel": "8"
    };
    var gaugeConfig5 = {
        "canvasHolderId": "XML",
            "width": "150",
            "height": "150",
            "circleColor": "#222",
            "arcColor": "#F39C12",
            "canvasFillColor": "#333",
            "textPosition": "inside",
            "skillLevel": "7.5"
    };
    var gaugeConfig6 = {
        "canvasHolderId": "JAVA",
            "width": "150",
            "height": "150",
            "circleColor": "#222",
            "arcColor": "#E67E22",
            "canvasFillColor": "#333",
            "textPosition": "inside",
            "skillLevel": "9"
    };
    var gaugeConfig7 = {
        "canvasHolderId": "MVC",
            "width": "150",
            "height": "150",
            "circleColor": "#222",
            "arcColor": "#E67E22",
            "canvasFillColor": "#333",
            "textPosition": "inside",
            "skillLevel": "8.5"
    };
    var gaugeConfig8 = {
        "canvasHolderId": "SP",
            "width": "150",
            "height": "150",
            "circleColor": "#222",
            "arcColor": "#D35400",
            "canvasFillColor": "#333",
            "textPosition": "inside",
            "skillLevel": "6.5"
    };
    var gaugeConfig9 = {
        "canvasHolderId": "WB",
            "width": "150",
            "height": "150",
            "circleColor": "#222",
            "arcColor": "#E74C3C",
            "canvasFillColor": "#333",
            "textPosition": "inside",
            "skillLevel": "7"
    };
    var gaugeConfig10 = {
        "canvasHolderId": "SQL",
            "width": "150",
            "height": "150",
            "circleColor": "#222",
            "arcColor": "#E74C3C",
            "canvasFillColor": "#333",
            "textPosition": "inside",
            "skillLevel": "8"
    };
    var gaugeConfig11 = {
        "canvasHolderId": "HB",
            "width": "150",
            "height": "150",
            "circleColor": "#222",
            "arcColor": "#C0392B",
            "canvasFillColor": "#333",
            "textPosition": "inside",
            "skillLevel": "6.5"
    };

    function drawGauge(gc) {
        var W = gc.width;
        var H = gc.height;
        var degrees = 0;
        var new_degrees = 0;
        var difference = 0;
        var color = gc.arcColor;
        var bgcolor = gc.circleColor;
        var text = gc.skillLevel;
        var animation_loop, redraw_loop;
        var me = this;
        var canvasHolder = document.getElementById(gc.canvasHolderId);
        var canvasCreator = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvasCreator.id = _randomId();
        canvasCreator.width = gc.width;
        canvasCreator.height = gc.height;
        canvasHolder.appendChild(canvasCreator);
        var canvas = document.getElementById(canvasCreator.id);

        function _randomId() {
            var d = new Date();
            return "canvas" + d.getFullYear() + "" + d.getMonth() + "" + d.getDay() + "" + d.getHours() + "" + d.getSeconds() + "" + d.getMilliseconds() * Math.random();
        }

        function _init() {
            ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, W, H);
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.strokeStyle = bgcolor;
            ctx.lineWidth = 15;
            ctx.arc(W / 2, H / 2, 50, 0, Math.PI * 2, false); //you can see the arc now
            ctx.stroke();
            var radians = degrees * Math.PI / 180;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.strokeStyle = color;
            ctx.lineWidth = 15;
            ctx.arc(W / 2, H / 2, 50, 0 - 90 * Math.PI / 180, radians - 90 * Math.PI / 180, false);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.font = "30px bebas";
            text_width = ctx.measureText(text).width;
            ctx.fillText(text, W / 2 - text_width / 2, H / 2 + 12);
        }

        function _animate_to() {
            if (degrees == new_degrees) clearInterval(animation_loop);
            if (degrees < new_degrees) degrees++;
            else degrees--;
            _init();
        }

        function _draw() {

            if (typeof animation_loop !== 'undefined') clearInterval(animation_loop);

            new_degrees = Math.round((text * 3600) / 100);
            difference = new_degrees - degrees;

            animation_loop = setInterval(function () {
                _animate_to();
            }, 1000 / difference);
        }
        _draw();
    }
    new drawGauge(gaugeConfig);
    new drawGauge(gaugeConfig1);
    new drawGauge(gaugeConfig2);
    new drawGauge(gaugeConfig3);
    new drawGauge(gaugeConfig4);
    new drawGauge(gaugeConfig5);
    new drawGauge(gaugeConfig6);
    new drawGauge(gaugeConfig7);
    new drawGauge(gaugeConfig8);
    new drawGauge(gaugeConfig9);
    new drawGauge(gaugeConfig10);
    new drawGauge(gaugeConfig11);
});
```

Comment: I'm confused. First you said `It only works one time when clicked`, and then you said `I want to modify it in such a way that it will only execute once when clicked`.

Comment: Which portion of this is or is not working? IT's a bit hard to tell from your question.

Comment: It might be easier to get help if you create an example that fits in a single page instead of pasting hundreds of lines of code from your original application.

Comment: Meaning that the current code works fine when clicked. It would not execute when clicked for second time or no matter what. I want to achieve same for scroll event as well.
If either clicked or scrolled, it will execute once and would not execute after that.

Comment: You can click on the link to see it live which would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you are saying what I think you are saying, you want a single fire of the inner contents, but you want either scroll or click to do it.

```
var skillsClicked = false;   // <----  Add this OUTSIDE of the click function
$('.skills').on('click scroll', function () {
    if (skillsClicked === true) return false;  // <---- Then add this
    skillsClicked = true;     // <-----  And the final update
    //rest of your code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your on-click code into a function, lets callit "function playGauge(evt)', then add it as handler to each event you want to triger it:

```
$('.skills).click(playGauge)
$('.skills).hover(playGauge)
//... etc.
```

Comment: It's works hover. But I want it to run with .scroll method to catch scroll event.

Answer (score 0):

Your explanation is really confusion. But I guess what you are trying to say is that the code is working correctly but you want the `click` to be changed with `scroll`.

You can copy the `click` and changed that

```
$('.skills').on('click', function () {
```

to this

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
```

Comment: Yes, but I only want to execute the function once when a particular div is scrolled.